# Robocopy with Task scheduler in invisible mode for KIOSK mode or alternative

Tags: command-line, robocopy, kiosk

Computer Setup: Computer in KIOSK mode through Shelllauncher on Windows 10 LTSC.

Problem trying to solve: I am looking to move local files on network drive.

Solution I found which have some gaps: robocopy code which is saved as .bat file: Robocopy [source path] [destination path] /xx log+: [path]/logFile.log

Then this batch file have been configured with Windows Task Scheduler to run everyday.

Problem with this solution which I trying to resolve and can use help: There is a momentary command prompt pop up when the batch file is initiated during scheduled time through Windows Task scheduler. Since this is a computer with KIOSK mode so I am looking for something so the command prompt doesn't pop up and instead stay in invisible mode. We cannot use vbscript to call the batch file as vb script are not allowed by IT.

I am also open for alternative to robocopy or something which can be used to move file from local to network drive.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: https://youtu.be/pF7yf6YuEdc?feature=shared&t=730

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277963/how-to-call-cmd-without-opening-a-window

Comment: @Gantendo: Thanks but unfortunately that's not what I am looking forward. What that does will still take away screen focus for a computer in a KIOSK mode app. We do not want that to happen at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Task Scheduler in the task's security options, try the option "Run whether the user is logged on or not" instead of "Run only when user is logged on" which is the default.

Also, try to call robocopy directly instead of through a batch file.

Comment: 1. We cannot use that option to run when user is logged in as we are using a service account dedicated for KIOSK computer. In order to run whether user is logged or not, we would have to give permission to the service account to log on as a batch user which could open other can of worms. 
2. I was not able to run robocopy directly, perhaps I am not sure what the syntax is? Can you please help with that? On related to this, I did try to run as powershell script but that behaved the same way as batch file.

Comment: In order to run robocopy directly, in a command prompt, enter "where robocopy" and it gives you the path, normally "C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe". If you call it with full path it should work.
Also, on the permissions issue, AFAICS your kiosk user only needs access to the ressources that are being copied, i.e. the local drive and the network drive that you are copying to, not so?

Comment: I tried robocopy directly and it behaved the same way.

Our setup is :
Service account dedicated for KIOSK purpose will be using that application in KIOSK mode on Windows 10 on a production computer. 
Service account have write access on network drive where it saves all test data at the end of the test, however as back up we will be saving it locally in case of network outage. 
Now, we want to automate the local drive content to network drive and scheduling with robocopy was one approach but the cmd, powershell takes up focus which leads to issue on the manufacturing Software.